# How to remove characters in r

Tags: r

I have a character sting like  `"x$var1"`.
I want to eliminate the `"x$"` so I only have `"var1"`.
It is probably simple but I am new to R.  Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: type ?gsub in the command box. This will bring up the documentation for the function you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use function `sub`. Double `\\` is used because `$` is a special regular expression character, so it needs to be escaped.

```
sub("x\\$", replacement = "", x = "x$var1")
[1] "var1"
```

Or we can use `fixed=TRUE` and remove the escape  characters`\\`

```
sub("x$", replacement = "", x = "x$var1", fixed=TRUE)
#[1] "var1"
```

Comment: That works like a breeze, thanks!  Follow up... is there any way to use a for loop to do that multiple times?  Something like:  for(i in c("var1", "var2") { variable <- sub("x$, replacement = "", x = "x$i") }  So if you print this you get var1 and var2?